# Troubles with returns declaration on the first parser rule in an ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am using **returns** for my parser rules which works for all parser rules except the first one. If the first parser rule in my grammer uses the **returns** declaration ANTLR4 complains as follows:

**expecting ARG_ACTION while matching a rule**

If I add another parser rule above which does not use "returns" ANTLR does not complain.

Here you have a grammar reduced to the problem:

```
grammar FirstParserRuleReturnIssue;
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
aRule returns [String s]: ID { $s = $ID.text; };
```

I searched to find a special role of the first rule that could explain the behaviour but did not find anything. Is it a bug? Do I miss some understanding?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to place parser rules (start with a lowercase letter) before lexer rules (start with an uppercase letter) in your grammar. After encountering a lexer rule, the `[` triggers a `LEXER_CHAR_SET` instead of `ARG_ACTION`, so the token stream seen by the compiler looks like you're passing a set of characters where the return value should be.